# Scipy interp1d cubic interpolation results different between scipy 0.18.1 and 1.2.1?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, cubic-spline

The results obtained by a `kind='cubic'` interpolation using `interp1d` seem to change between `scipy 0.18.1` and `1.2.1`. I use `python 2.7.12`/`numpy 1.12.0` with the former and `python 3.6.8`/`numpy 1.16.2` with the latter. Which change in the source code is responsible for the different results?

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1000)
n_p = 6
n_p_interpolated = 11

a = np.linspace(0,5,n_p)
a_interpolated = np.linspace(0,5,n_p_interpolated)
b = np.random.rand(n_p)

b_interpolated = interp1d(a,b,kind='cubic')(a_interpolated)

print('b:', b)
print('b_interpolated:', b_interpolated)

plt.ion()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(a,b,label='original data')
plt.plot(a_interpolated,b_interpolated,label='interpolated data')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(-1,6)
plt.ylim(-0.2,1)
```

With `scipy 0.18.1`:

```
('b:', array([ 0.65358959,  0.11500694,  0.95028286,  0.4821914 ,  0.87247454,
        0.21233268]))
('b_interpolated:', array([ 0.65358959, -0.1292027 ,  0.11500694,  0.64514961,  0.95028286,
        0.75328508,  0.4821914 ,  0.58350879,  0.87247454,  0.95267129,
        0.21233268]))
```

With `scipy 1.2.1`:

```
b: [0.65358959 0.11500694 0.95028286 0.4821914  0.87247454 0.21233268]
b_interpolated: [ 0.65358959 -0.05237073  0.11500694  0.62584926  0.95028286  0.75365451
  0.4821914   0.60133139  0.87247454  0.88101143  0.21233268]
```

All interpolated values (that are not in the original grid) are different, some quite drastically (such as the second one).

Comment: Seems to be so. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.19.0.html#other-changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the algorithm for constructing the spline was changed. In scipy 0.18 and below, it used the `find_smoothest` algorithm (see scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py in the scipy source repository, pre scipy 0.19.0). From version 0.19.0 onwards, the default algorithm for cubics is not-a-knot.

Comment: So it seems a matter of boundary treatments. What distinguishes the two conceptually (I am not an expert on the topic)?

Comment: The spline interpolant is a solution of a certain sustem of equations. Boundary conditions are needed to complete the system. So, these are solutions of two slightly different systems, hence possibly different.